# Error: Could not find an option named "sourcemap" when running SASS and Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, node-modules, node-sass, grunt-contrib-sass

I am trying to run Grunt and SASS in order to uglify and minify javascript, CSS and SCSS.
I am trying to run grunt in a RHEL8 AWS EC2 Instance and have installed the required dependencies:

**NodeJS**: v10.24.1

**NPM**: 6.14.12

**Ruby**: ruby 2.5.9p229 (2021-04-05 revision 67939) [x86_64-linux]

**Gem**: 2.7.6.3

**Grunt**: grunt-cli v1.4.3

**SASS**: 1.35.2 compiled with dart2js 2.13.4

However, when I try to run grunt, I am getting the below error:

> Could not find an option named "sourcemap".
>
> Usage: sass <input.scss> [output.css]
> sass <input.scss>:<output.css> :

[image: Screenshot 1]

Grunt seems to be running fine, however there seems to be some issue with SASS. This seems to work fine in my local machine. However, I cannot run grunt within the EC2 instance.

These were the commands that I used to download the dependencies:

```
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config -y
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs -y
npm install -g grunt
yum install ruby -y
npm install -g sass
```

Is this any sort of dependency issue? Can someone please help?

Comment: Pretty cold in here...

Comment: Not anymone! ;-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a way to resolve this issue. In the above question, I tried to install SASS using NPN. But instead of doing that, I tried to install SASS using Ruby-Gem.

Following are the set of commands that I used to resolve this issue:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm reload
rvm requirements run
rvm install 2.7
gem install sass:3.7.4
```

Ruby Version: 2.7
SASS Version: 3.7.4

By doing so, I was able to install SASS the proper way and everything worked as expected.

Thanks!